# Can someone please advise me about dummy coding in SPSS & inconsistent outputs with R/Stata?

Tags: r, regression, spss

I am conducting a linear regression analysis for categorical variables using dummy coding in SPSS. I am then cross-checking the results in R. However, I have encountered a discrepancy where one of the dummy coding results is inconsistent with R, showing completely different outputs although the other dummy variables are consistent between the two software programs.
I am trying to identify the possible issues that could be causing this discrepancy, but I cannot able to find a solution thus far. Can someone help me with this problem? (I got the same result in R & stata for that variable)

Comment: Could you post the relevant outputs? Did you use exactly the same data with separate dummy variables? (If you entered the categorical variable as one factor, the reason may be that SPSS and R use different default reference categories).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did the same dataset but I copied that computed categorical data from SPSS into the R working file. Do you think that is the problem? 
Now I completely export my SPSS dataset into R, then I got the same results.

Comment: So you got identical results when you loaded/imported the full  dataset to R? In that case the problem was very likely in the data import process, but it's really difficult to say what it was exactly. For that you'd probably need to post the original (non-identical) outputs from SPSS and R. But if you got identical results now, the practical problem was solved at least :)

Comment: Yes, At least I can move forward now. ^^ Thank you so much, Sointu